# Resetting Password inside Django Save Function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently using django rest password reset urls for my password reset needs and I have it attributed to a URL:

```
url("^password-reset/", include("django_rest_passwordreset.urls", namespace="password_reset")),
```

However, I would like to call this endpoint in a save method of a model using the email attributed to the user model. Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: Why do you want to call the endpoint?. It isn't better just reset the password directly, using the set_password function?

Comment: Will I be able to send an email to the user prompting them to set their password?

Comment: My main goal is to be able to create a user within django admin and then have an email be sent to them to set their password. II already have a save function defined within my model.

Comment: So you are registering the user with user's email id and giving them access to their account with these password reset tokens, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't *'call an **endpoint** in a save method'*, but you can make use of [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/) to achieve this.

`send_password_reset_token` is a receiver function that triggered when a new user is created and sends a password reset link to the newly registered user's email automatically.

```
from datetime import timedelta

from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from rest_framework import exceptions
from django_rest_passwordreset.models import ResetPasswordToken, clear_expired, get_password_reset_token_expiry_time, \
    get_password_reset_lookup_field

from django_rest_passwordreset.signals import reset_password_token_created

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def send_password_reset_token(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):


    if created:

        email = instance.email

        # before we continue, delete all existing expired tokens
        password_reset_token_validation_time = get_password_reset_token_expiry_time()

        # datetime.now minus expiry hours
        now_minus_expiry_time = timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=password_reset_token_validation_time)

        # delete all tokens where created_at < now - 24 hours
        clear_expired(now_minus_expiry_time)

        # find a user by email address (case insensitive search)
        users = User.objects.filter(**{'{}__iexact'.format(get_password_reset_lookup_field()): email})

        active_user_found = False

        # iterate overall users and check if there is any user that is active
        # also check whether the password can be changed (is useable), as there could be users that are not allowed
        # to change their password (e.g., LDAP user)
        for user in users:
            if user.eligible_for_reset():
                active_user_found = True

        # No active user found, raise a validation error
        # but not if DJANGO_REST_PASSWORDRESET_NO_INFORMATION_LEAKAGE == True
        if not active_user_found and not getattr(settings, 'DJANGO_REST_PASSWORDRESET_NO_INFORMATION_LEAKAGE', False):
            raise exceptions.ValidationError({
                'email': [_(
                    "There is no active user associated with this e-mail address or the password can not be changed")],
            })

        # last but not least: iterate over all users that are active and can change their password
        # and create a Reset Password Token and send a signal with the created token
        for user in users:
            if user.eligible_for_reset():
                # define the token as none for now
                token = None

                # check if the user already has a token
                if user.password_reset_tokens.all().count() > 0:
                    # yes, already has a token, re-use this token
                    token = user.password_reset_tokens.all()[0]
                else:
                    # no token exists, generate a new token
                    token = ResetPasswordToken.objects.create(user=user)

        # send an e-mail to the user
        context = {
            'current_user': token.user,
            'username': token.user.username,
            'email': token.user.email,
            'reset_password_url': "{}?token={}".format(reverse('password_reset:reset-password-request'), token.key)
        }

        send_mail(
            'Subject here',
            f'Your password_reset link is {context["reset_password_url"]}',
            'from@example.com',
            ['to@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

[ResetPasswordRequestToken generation](https://github.com/anexia-it/django-rest-passwordreset/blob/1c5bbc324a1e3859536299cf73099fcbda1ce3e6/django_rest_passwordreset/views.py#L89)
[Django email documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#module-django.core.mail)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of signal to send email:

considering a Django app named **profiles**(you need to find and replace all occurrence of `profiles` with your app name).

create new file `profiles/signals.py`:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django_rest_passwordreset.signals import reset_password_token_created
from django.urls import reverse

@receiver(reset_password_token_created)
def send_token_email(sender, instance, reset_password_token, *args, **kwargs):
    reset_password_url = f"{instance.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('password_reset:reset-password-confirm'))}"
    message = f"Goto <a href='{reset_password_url}'>{reset_password_url}</a> and enter new password and token({reset_password_token.key})"

    # send an e-mail to the user
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    send_mail('Password reset',message,'noreply@somehost.com', [reset_password_token.user.email])
```

update `profiles/app.py` add `ready` method:

```
# ...

class ProfilesConfig(AppConfig):
    # ...

    def ready(self):
        import profiles.signals
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to send user an email after you add a user from admin.

You can do that by adding a `save_model` function in the admin. You can also send the password reset email using `PasswordResetForm`.

The full code cane be something like this:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        form = PasswordResetForm(data={"email": obj.email})
        # calling save will send the email
        form.save()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Documentation for PasswordResetForm: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm

Comment: it seems like op wants to use django_rest_passwordreset.

Answer (score 0):

All you need do is send an email to them with a token and require that token from them.

if you use a save method within your model, that method will be called every time there is a saved change to an entry in that model which may not be what you want.